# Do I need low poly model assets for videogames - enviroment or "world"

Tags: modeling, world

I have a question about the creation of assets for video games.
Usually for the game objects a high poly model is prepared, to then transfer the details on a low poly model, so that it can be rendered in real time. Is it a work that is always done with any object? the polygonal models of the characters in general imagine yes but the rest? I refer to the environment, the structures, vehicles etc. from various videos released by some studios you can see the low in engine models, so I guess so.

I was especially interested in the environment, a snowy mountain for example. I do not think you do this reasoning even in this case, after all change the game environment seems fast enough with the most popular engines. I could not elaborate on it, could you help me?
thanks in advance and sorry for my english, I do not know if I was clear xD

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for a different stackexchange, maybe https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might also want to research "Level of Detail" in regards to rendering